# Can't re-install Postgresql in Debian Squeeze

Tags: postgresql, installation, debian, apt

I just installed Debian Squeeze to work as a Postgresql server, but when I try to recover a backup something went wrong. After a search, I deleted the cluster (data dir) and uninstalled Postgresql. Afterwards, I was unable to make the server work (install, remove, purge).

What can I do so that `apt-get install postgresql` would behave as if it was a fresh Debian install?

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Really a shot in the dark without the actual error message, but in the olden days, I had to manually delete the user "postgres" before reinstalling would work.